# Ionic2 alert with dropdown?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building an Ionic2 app. I have an alert like following:

[image]

```
constructor(private platform: Platform, public nav : NavController, 
    public exhibitionSurveyObjectService : ExhibitionSurveyObjectService ) {

    this.initializeMap();
    this.nav=nav;

    this.testArray=[];
    this.area=null;
  }

  addSurveyObject(){

    let prompt = Alert.create({
      title: 'Subscribe to our service',
      message: "All the fields are necessary",
      inputs: [
      {
        name: 'name',
        placeholder: 'Name'
      },
      ....
      {
        name: 'cycle',
        placeholder: 'Cycle: once/weekly/monthly'
      },
      {
        name: 'object_type',
        placeholder: 'Farm/Solarpanel/plain'
      },
      ],
      buttons: [
      ....   
      {
        text: 'Save',
        handler: data => {
          this.createExhibitionSuveyObject(data);
        }
      }
      ]
    });

    this.nav.present(prompt);
  }

  createExhibitionSuveyObject(data: any){

    var cycle = data.cycle;
    cycle = cycle.toUpperCase()
    console.log(cycle)

    var type = data.object_type;
    type = type.toUpperCase()
    console.log(type)

    this.exhibitionSurveyObjectService.addObject(
      data.name, data.farmer_email, 
      data.farmer_name, data.size, data.path, cycle, type).subscribe(

      response => {

        this.exhibitionSurveyObjects = response;
        this.sayThanks();

      },
      error =>  {

        this.errorMessage = <any>error; 
        console.log("error")
      }
      );
    }

    sayThanks(){

      let alert = Alert.create({
        title: 'Thank you!',
        subTitle: 'We have received your data, we will get back to you soon!',
        buttons: [{
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: () => {

            this.nav.push(HomePage)
          }
        }]
      });
      this.nav.present(alert);

    }
```

**I want the last two fields to be dropdowns. How can I achieve this?**

**UPDATE:** updated the code snippet with some more code. How it can be updated to use Modal instead of alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you can see in [Ionic2 docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/Alert/)

> Alerts can also include several different inputs whose data can be
>   passed back to the app. Inputs can be used as a simple way to prompt
>   users for information. **Radios, checkboxes and text inputs are all
>   accepted, but they cannot be mixed. For example, an alert could have
>   all radio button inputs, or all checkbox inputs, but the same alert
>   cannot mix radio and checkbox inputs**.

And...

> If you require a complex form UI which doesn't fit within the
>   guidelines of an alert then we recommend building the form within a
>   modal instead.

So you'll have to create a new `Component` with that form and then use it to create the `Modal`:

```
import { Modal, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component(...)
class YourPage {

 constructor(nav: NavController) {
   this.nav = nav;
 }

 presentSubscriptionModal() {
   let subscriptionModal = Modal.create(Subscription, { yourParam: paramValue });
   this.nav.present(subscriptionModal);
 }

}

@Component(...)
class Subscription{

 constructor(params: NavParams) {
   let param = params.get('yourParam');
 }

}
```

Comment: So do I completely remove the alert and instead use Modal? I am updating the code snippet with some more code.

Comment: @Nitish Yes exactly, Alertboxes are for very fast prompts.. even if you need 2 textfields I would definitely go for a modal for a better UI!

Comment: Thanks! I implemented it that way!

Comment: Glad to hear that :) I've also used a Modal in a recent app to show countries and cities because there were 100+ options in some cases and the performance of the alert was terrible. That way I was able to include a searchbar inside the Modal and also show the first 30 matching results only to improve the performance even in slow devices.